# Recursive function to generate flat array from hierarchical array Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, hash, flatten

I have a ruby hash array like this

```
string = "[{\"id\":13},{\"id\":15,\"children\":[{\"id\":16},{\"id\":17,\"children\":[{\"id\":19}]},{\"id\":18}]},{\"id\":14}]"
hash = Json.parse(string)
```

I am trying to create an ruby hash array like:

```
{13=>nil, 15=>nil, 16=>15, 17=>15, 19=>17, 18=>15, 14=>nil}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Nothing like `Json.parse(string)`, but `JSON.parse(string)` does work..`Json.parse(string)` will throw error.

Comment: I don't understand how your starting string/array maps onto your result.  Why does 13 => nil but 17 => 15?  I can't see that in the source string at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
def build_hash(arr, hash={}, parent=nil)
  return if arr.nil?
  arr.each do |item|
    hash[item['id']] = parent
    build_hash(item['children'], hash, item['id'])
  end
  hash
end

build_hash(hash)
# => {13=>nil, 15=>nil, 16=>15, 17=>15, 19=>17, 18=>15, 14=>nil}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just saw Uri post his solution, I was just finishing mine. Mine works on a Hash while his works on an Array (your input is actually an Array of Hashes, not a Hash). Otherwise they are roughly the same. I like his slightly better but for sake of variety:

```
@output = {}
def process(hash, parent=nil)
  id = hash['id']
  children = hash['children']
  @output[id] = parent
  children.each { |child| process(child, id) } unless children.nil?
end
hash.each { |h| process(h) }
p @output
# => {13=>nil, 15=>nil, 16=>15, 17=>15, 19=>17, 18=>15, 14=>nil}
```

Comment: The OP does not say it is a hash. They say it is a hash array. I also came up with almost the same answer as Uri's, based on array, but did not post it because that would be redundant. Considering it as an array is better in this case when you look at how the `["children"]` values are. Since you did it with a hash, you needed to call `hash.each` independently of the method.

Comment: @sawa Well let's say he's contradicting himself a bit because he names the variable to store the array of hashes, `hash` :-)

Comment: I agree that that is misleading (though not contradictory). I also noted that the OP even calls the expected result a hash array, when it is only a hash. That is wrong.